# Matlab/Octave 2D Discrete Fourier Transform

Tags: matlab, image-processing, octave, fft

I would like to recreate the steps in Octave as shown in the image, but I think I am doing it completely wrong.

```
I = imread('424a.png');

subplot(2,2,1);
imshow(I);
title('Original Image'); 

subplot(2,2,2);
F = fft2(I);
imshow(abs(F),[]);
title('FFT'); 

subplot(2,2,3);
imshow(log(abs(F)),[])
title('log - FFT'); 

F = fftshift(F);
subplot(2,2,4);
imshow(log(abs(F)),[])
title('centered - log - FFT');
```

[image]

Would be very thankful for help :)
Best regards!

EDIT: 
Now it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Show us the original image too. Also, where are your attempts to recreate the other 3 figures? You only plot 2, and you are not applying the log transform to the last one

Comment: Right. Here is the original picture: http://vda.univie.ac.at/Teaching/SIP/18s/Lab2/424a.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MATLAB log function for the log transformation. It helps to see a scaled version of the transform.

```
I = imread('testimage.png');

subplot(2,2,1);
imshow(I);
title('Original Image'); 

subplot(2,2,2);
F = fft2(I);
imshow(abs(F),[]);
title('FFT'); 

subplot(2,2,3);
imshow(log(abs(F)),[])
title('log - FFT'); 

F = fftshift(F);
subplot(2,2,4);
imshow(log(abs(F)),[])
title('centered - log - FFT');
```

[image]

Comment: Ah looks nice, but my picture is not an RGB image so is there a workaround for rgb2gray? Or is it not neccessary? Because if I read the image normally the other steps are only black.

Comment: Ok, but I still get this error: error: rgb2gray: the input must either be an RGB image or a colormap

Comment: Looks like your image is already in gray scale :) Skip that function. I updated the answer

Comment: Thank you! But I am only seeing the original and two dark images. Is it possible that this is a problem of Octave? :/

Comment: Refresh the page, I just updated the answer. I am not sure about the Octave, I used Matlab for this one. It is very generic operation, I don't think it should make difference.

Comment: Editet my question...I am not sure why I get black pictures

Comment: FFT has white corners, so it is correct. The last two needs scaling

Comment: You dont mean scaling like making larger, dont you? ;) I am not sure which scaling is meant :P I read something about imagesc with clim=[5 13], is ths helpful in my case or where can I use it?

Comment: I haven't got access to the original images, but I'm relatively sure your problem relates to [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/40636/23055) problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that F has a minimum value of 0 and when you take `log(F)` you will get a minimum of `-Inf`. The `imshow(F,[])` functions scales the picture between MIN and MAX so in your case it will appear as a black image. You could either add a small value to F before taking the log or set the limits manually [0 8.8] (8.8 is `log(max(F(:)))`)

EDIT1:

If I add a small constant in `imshow(log(abs(F)+1),[])` I get the following result (using Octave 4.2.1 under Ubuntu 17.10): 
[image]
The result differs some from the paper you showed but it looks like they don't have a linear greyscale colormap (It starts from a medium grey level)

EDIT2:

They seems to use a downsampled by 2 version of the image. If you downsample it using `imresize(I,0.5)` you will get at similar plot as in the paper.

[image]

Comment: edited my original post. Does not like the one how it should look like, but very near to it? Code is also updatet am I still doing something wrong?